# Issue in Kubernetes

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes

I'm already installed docker, then i install a kubernetes but docker service cannot is not working. Here i'm Attaching error images for your reference.

Docker Version:-docker-ce.x86_64  18.05.0.ce-3.fc26

Docker service status[image]

Docker service status-2[image]

If i'm creating kubernetes pod container, its not created and showing some error like this.

Here i'm Attaching error images for your reference.
Kubernetes pod container creating Error[image]

Kubernetes pod container creating Error-2[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. The docker installation should work. Since it is not clear to me with the info you provided, I just suggest this https://docs.docker.com/install/#supported-platforms.
2. The error for pod creation says your fedora.yaml contains invalid pod configuration in line 7 that is not as expected. You can see [sample-pod-template](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-overview/#pod-templates)

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. In addition, the text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.